# Minted caching in tikz externalize job

Tags: tikz-pgf, minted, tikz-external

Enabled caching options for `minted` and `tikz` lead to unexpected and inefficient caching. For every `tikz` figure that is externalized, all `minted` code blocks of the main document are cached within the `tikz` cache directory. For documents with e.g. >50 figures and >100 code listings, caching takes a long time and uses more disk space than would be necessary.

To give an example, consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cache]{minted}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/cache/}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[frame=none,fontsize=\small,linenos=true]{r}
plotdata <- data.frame(this = rnorm(20), that = rnorm(20))
\end{minted}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

\node[main node] (1) {1};
\node[main node] (2) [below left of=1] {2};
\node[main node] (3) [below right of=2] {3};
\node[main node] (4) [below right of=1] {4};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(1) edge node [left] {0.6} (4)
    edge [bend right] node[left] {0.3} (2)
    edge [loop above] node {0.1} (1)
(2) edge node [right] {0.4} (1)
    edge node {0.3} (4)
    edge [loop left] node {0.4} (2)
    edge [bend right] node[left] {0.1} (3)
(3) edge node [right] {0.8} (2)
    edge [bend right] node[right] {0.2} (4)
(4) edge node [left] {0.2} (3)
    edge [loop right] node {0.6} (4)
    edge [bend right] node[right] {0.2} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This leads to the directory structure:

```
.minted-mwe/
    475544BE9F571FFAF1D26ACA3A0AB8D0502F9AF18E3C3312853333EF1520885B.pygtex
    default.pygstyle
.minted-figures/
    cache/
        mwe-figure0/
            475544BE9F571FFAF1D26ACA3A0AB8D0502F9AF18E3C3312853333EF1520885B.pygtex
            default.pygstyle
figures/
    cache/
        mwe-figure0.aex
        mwe-figure0.dpth
        mwe-figure0.log
        mwe-figure0.md5
        mwe-figure0.pyg
```

where the `*.pygtex` files are redundant. I assume this is because of the way `tikz` does the system call to process the individual figures, i.e. all `minted` environments are considered in the external `pdflatex` job.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Am I missing/misconfiguring something?

Comment: Related: [Problem, when loading minted after \tikzexternalize](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270492/problem-when-loading-minted-after-tikzexternalize)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the way that `tikz` externalization works. If you look in the PGF/TikZ manual, under externalization, under "Details About The Process" (Section 50.4.5, page 625 in the version 3.0.0 manual), you will see that externalize works by **compiling the entire file** once for each image that is being externalized.  During this compiling process, all parts of the document not related to the current image are "silently thrown away". Unfortunately, while `minted` *output* is thrown away, `minted` will still check to see if cached content exists, and if not, create it.  Due to the way the compiling works for the externalized images, `minted` can't detect the existing cache from the main run, and will create a new cache.

There may be things that can be improved from the `tikz` side; I don't know enough about the technical details of the externalization process. From the `minted` side, the issue of duplication can be solved by loading `minted` conditionally (this needs `minted` 2.0):

```
\ifcsname tikzexternalrealjob\endcsname
    \usepackage[draft]{minted}
\else
    \usepackage[cache]{minted}
\fi
```

If the macro `\tikzexternalrealjob` exists (if the file is being compiled solely to externalize an image), this will load `minted` in draft mode. In draft mode, no external files are created and Python (Pygments) will never be called.  (Unused cache directories for the images will still be created...I will see about fixing that, and possibly adding `tikz` externalization detection, in the next `minted` release: [issue tracker](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/73).)  If `\tikzexternalrealjob` does not exist, then this is a normal compile, and `minted` proceeds normally.

Comment: Updated `minted` to 2.0; runs fine modulo the empty directories. Thanks for the workaround and keep up the good work!